# Another....html table not populating with mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have looked extensively through the site and have come to the conclusion that I am encountering a problem that many people do, yet none of the answers I have seen seem to work!

Basically, I am trying to populate an HTML table from the data stored in a mySQL table. The data is in a table called "categories". When I load the page, the table headers appear but no table data.

I have written and rewritten my code no less than 4 times - it works fine as an "ul" or when rendered as just  plain text, but as soon as I put it into a "table" to seems to stop working!

Here's my code:

```
<?php
include("includes/dbconnect.php"); //This works fine as tested on the page

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
$myData = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$product = mysql_fetch_array($myData);

?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    //This plain text works
<?php do {
echo $product['title']." <br />"; 
} while ($product = mysql_fetch_array($myData));
//-----------------------------------------
    //Table - doesnt work
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Sport</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Shipping</th>
</tr>";
while ($product = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$product['title']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $product['category'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $product['sport'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $product['team'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $product['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $product['shipping'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>


</body>
</html>
```

I really am at my wits end, Ive worked my way through countless YouTube tutorials and still for some reason the code wont work. Can anyone help?

Comment: print_r($product) after the start of the while loop, does it display what you are expecting?

Comment: If you fetched the data already, you cannot do that again!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code contains many bugs and implementation

try this if it works for you :

```
<?php
include("includes/dbconnect.php"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
$myData = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    //This plain text works
<?php 

if(mysql_num_rows ($myData) > 0)
{
    $html = "<table border=1><tr> 
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Sport</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Shipping</th></tr>";

    while ($product = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
    {   
        $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td>".$product['title']."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$product['category']."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$product['sport']."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$product['team']."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>" . $product['shipping'] . "</td>";
        $html .=  "</tr>";
    }
    $html .=  "</table>";
    echo $html;
}
else
{
    echo "No Product Found";
}   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If this works for you, you can figure out the problems or I will explain :)

Comment: great answer - simple and easy to implement! Even I understood it! Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You've already run `mysql_fetch_array` in a do while loop at the top of your code. You aren't able to pull a result row more than once. Instead, push all of the the returned rows on to an array:

```
$products = array();
while ($product = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
    $products[] = $product;
}
```

You can then loop through `$products` as many times as you'd like to build out your page. So for your table, this would look like:

```
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Sport</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Shipping</th>
</tr>";
foreach($products as $item) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $item['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $item['category'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $item['sport'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $item['team'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $item['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $item['shipping'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";    

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didnt know where to place the first block of php (whether inside a 'do while' loop or not. But thank you again for reworking the code!

Answer (score 0):

if that code really looks like this remove the do-while loop and everything where you iterate over your `$mydata` and it will work since you waste the internal mysql-counter

meaning in the second loop your `$result` is already at the end, either you query again OR you push all the results in an array for multiple use

Comment: I didn't know how to push the results into an array - but someone answered that just after your post - so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have already pulled your data once with this.....`$product = mysql_fetch_array($myData);`
so just use this array with foreach loop....

```
foreach($product as $sProduct){
// User $sProduct to access that single product.
}
```